# Wifi USB Adapters stop working after a couple of months

Tags: windows, networking, network-adapter

My Belkin Dual band USB adapter just stopped working. It doesn't work no matter how much I try troubleshooting it. I get an error:

```
USB device not recognised
```

This is third time in last six months this has happened. I am not sure what's the issue here. Is it something I should accept as a part of the deal? Before this, I had netgear adapters, both of them stopped working in about two months.

I have got a desktop computer and don't want to go through the same cycle again, would I be better off getting a PCI network card instead?

I leave my computer on for months, can that be a part of the problem?

Comment: I would be concerned that the desktop computer is frying USB devices.

Comment: do they still work in other computers?

Comment: Nope, I tried it with my macbook but no luck. I also tried it with my ubuntu installation. Device not recognised

Comment: Does this happen to strictly wireless devices?

Comment: Yes, it happened to wifi receptors. I ordered NIC based receptor the day I posted this question and it has worked very well so far. It is cheaper & has better reception. I forgot this question as I think it's just planned obsolescence from belkin as a couple of my colleagues have had the same problem after a certain amount of time.